# paypal javascript button - how to specify browser success url?

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am prototyping a payment via paypal and am stuck on how to specify the URL the browser should redirect/link to after a payment.

```
<script src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=stan-facilitator@merkwelt.com" 
    data-button="buynow" 
    data-name="New Bot" 
    data-quantity="1" 
    data-amount="0.99" 
    data-shipping="0" 
    data-tax="0" 
    data-callback="http://www.merkwelt.com/people/stan/paypal/success.html" 
    data-env="sandbox"
></script>
```

I am aware about the difference between callback (for reporting) and a return url (what happens in the browser). I like the browser to redirect back to my site after the payment has been handled. How can I do that?

It feels like I am missing something since this should be a standard setting for anyone using those buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it, this URL can be specified with **data-return**.

```
<script src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=stan-facilitator@merkwelt.com" 
    data-button="buynow" 
    data-name="New Bot" 
    data-quantity="1" 
    data-amount="0.99" 
    data-shipping="0" 
    data-tax="0" 
    data-callback="http://www.merkwelt.com/people/stan/paypal/callback" 
    data-return="http://www.merkwelt.com/people/stan/paypal/success.html" 
    data-env="sandbox"
></script>
```

via https://github.com/paypal/JavaScriptButtons/issues/48#issuecomment-17439860

Comment: You can add any of the variables by prefixing them with data- from the main list at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377946/paypal-javascript-button-how-to-specify-browser-success-url